# Converting html for mysql - what to do with <br/>s?

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

I’m converting a number of html documents into csv files to upload into MySQL – I’m replacing html div’s etc with tabs as necessary in a text editor  to get the data into the columns, then pasting into a spreadsheet and saving as CSV. This is working fine

A couple of ‘fields’ have data on more than one line, which in html is achieved by using `br’s`, leaving these in the CSV displays the data in the required format.

I’ve also produced a script to add/amend data and for the multi line fields I’m using textareas and then outputting using `nl2br()` which again displays the data as required. But the uploaded data with br’s  is displayed in the add/amend script as a continuous line with the `br’s`.

Question – Is there anything I can do when manipulating the html data to replace the `br’s` so that they appear as multi lines in the textareas ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace 
 with "\n"

```
  <?

    $string="Some stuff <br/> some other";
    $string=str_replace("<br/>","\n",$string);

    ?>

    <textarea><?=$string?></textarea>
```

Comment: That's interesting. It works in php, but not if I replace the br's by \n in the csv file before I upload - which would be easier as I can use 'find and replace'.

It looks as if I'll have to upload and then run a script.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace with \n instead of br tag

Comment: I can't get that to work by changing it in the csv file.